# How to avoid blank space for title in R markdown v2

Tags: r, r-markdown

I would not like to have blank space in my pdf output, that surely stands for no title method in R markdown while knitting pdf.

I would like not to have title and have text starting from the begging of the page. Can anyone  can tell me how to do that?

My code, so far, looks like this:

```
---
output: 
   pdf_document:
      highlight: pygments
      toc: false
      number_sections: true
---
text
```

Thanks for any advice !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this level of customization you'll want to change the TeX template Pandoc uses:

1. Copy the default TeX template used by rmarkdown (you can find the path by running `system.file("rmd/latex/default.tex", package="rmarkdown")`)
2. Edit the file to remove the title, adjust margins, etc. and save as e.g. `notitle.tex`
3. Add `template: notitle.tex` to the settings to `pdf_document`.

Comment: I've followed this instruction, but am getting the error message:
`pandoc.exe: Could not find data file templates\notitle.tex`