# Can I use `hyperref` in R markdown2

Tags: r, r-markdown

Is it possible to have links in the Table of Contents using R markdown v2?

In LaTeX this would be by loading `\package{hyperref}`

Comment: It should be possible. What happens when you try it?

Comment: `! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.` when putting after the front matter, opens in HTML mode if in front.

Comment: You can modify the TeX template used by RMarkdown v2 so that it loads the `hyperref` package. This answer has details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25513671/how-to-avoid-blank-space-for-title-in-r-markdown-v2/25533572#25533572

Comment: thanks, will have a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this question is actually mentioned here:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24208889/how-to-specify-numbered-sections-in-pandocs-front-matter#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24208889/how-to-specify-numbered-sections-in-pandocs-front-matter#_=_)

As mentioned this YAML option is not easy to find.

**Solution**

add the following to the YAML front matter:

```
header-includes:
    - \usepackage{hyperref}
```

Comment: Looks like `hyperref` might alreay be included anyway, just see it as an example of adding ANY LaTeX package to R markdown.